# Date comparison in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have compared the dates as start date should be less than end date, but for some dates it is not validating.

I have written like this but it is throwing error for the dates and both are date columns:

```
Start date:'27-AUG-2023'
End Date: '26-OCT-2023'


if BUP.INS_START_DATE< BUP.INS_END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY' THEN
   p_message:=null;
else
   p_message:='INSURANCE START DATE MUST BE ALWAYS LESS THAN INSURANCE END DATE.';
end if;
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if BUP.INS_START_DATE< BUP.INS_END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY' THEN
```

is obviously invalid; what is `DD-MON-YYYY` doing here, alone in the Universe?

---

> ... the dates and both are **date** columns

What does "date" mean here? That columns' datatype is `DATE` (should be), or that value represents a date, but is stored into a `VARCHAR2` column (shouldn't be)?

If former (i.e. both are `DATE` datatypes), then you'd simply

```
if ins_start_date < ins_end_date then ...
```

If latter, then you should use `to_date` function with appropriate format model:

```
if to_date(ins_start_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') < to_date(ins_end_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') then ...
```

Otherwise, without the `to_date` function, you'd compare *STRINGS* and the result won't be correct (for example, 9-MAR-1987 will be "larger" than 23-JUN-2022 because 9 is larger than 2 (in 23)).